# Using plus signs in query strings with HTTParty

Tags: httparty

I'm trying to get this url with HTTparty:

`http://collections.museumvictoria.com.au/api/search?hasimages=yes&collectingarea=royal+exhibition+building&page=1`

I'm using the query:

`items = get("http://collections.museumvictoria.com.au/api/search", query: {has images: "yes", collecting area: "royal+exhibition+building", page: 1})`

This returns 0 results however if I just copy and past the url into a browser it does return data. From my other tests it looks as though only collecting areas with plus signs in them fail to return results `collectingarea: "arms"` works).

Any idea how we should properly encode the plus signs to make this work in HTTParty?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTParty version >= v0.13.4 It's encode the query values internally.
However you can Override httparty's query strings normalizer.
Also you need to put underscore between words in query keys like has_images, collecting_area.

I tested this code and it works for me:

```
require 'httparty'

class Test
    include HTTParty
    def self.test
        puts self.get("http://collections.museumvictoria.com.au/api/search", query: {has_images: "yes", collecting_area: "royal+exhibition+building", page: 1})
    end
end

Test.test
```